# Indirectly changing object state in const member method

Tags: c++, constants, wrapper, composition

Lets say we have some association, modeled as a class, which has several bank accounts on which it accepts donations. The public can donate to each of these, or get a list of all bank accounts from the charity, pick one, and then donate directly to some specified account.

Of course, the association will only return a `const&` to its bank accounts so that the public cannot arbitrarily change (or even replace) them. But it would still be nice that - after getting the `const&` to the accounts and then picking one (by index), a user will be directly able to donate to the account - i.e using a member method of the account, and not having to go back to the association itself, remember the number of account, etc.

I came up with the following solution, which seems to work:

```cpp
namespace detail {
        class VirtualAssociation {
        public:
            virtual void donate(size_t account_number, int amount) = 0;
        };
    }

    class DonationsAccount {
    public:
        DonationsAccount(detail::VirtualAssociation* association, size_t account_number) :
        _association(association), _account_number(account_number), _money(0) {}

        /*! put some money on this account. Of course not const */
        void put(int amount) {_money += amount;}

        /*! Donate some money. Will be const, but actually does the same as the put() method*/
        void donate(int amount) const {_association->donate(_account_number, amount); }

        /*! Get balance of this account */
        int balance() const {return _money; }

    private:
        detail::VirtualAssociation* _association;
        size_t _account_number;
        int _money;
    };

    class Association : public detail::VirtualAssociation {
    public:

        Association() : _accounts() {_accounts.emplace_back(this, 0); }

        /*! Donate some money on a certain account of this association */
        void donate(size_t account_number, int amount) override {_accounts[account_number].put(amount); }

        /*! Get the list of accounts of this association */
        const std::vector<DonationsAccount>& accounts() const {return _accounts; }

    private:
        std::vector<DonationsAccount> _accounts;
    };


    int main() {
        Association association;
        association.donate(0,10);
        // association.accounts()[0].put(); //illegal, because put is a non-const method
        association.accounts()[0].donate(5);

        std::cout << "Balance on account 0: " << association.accounts()[0].balance() << std::endl;
        return 0;

    }
```

`gcc` compiles this with no warnings, and i also get the correct print output of `15`. But of course this feels like an ugly workaround, so my questions are

- **Does the above yield undefined behaviour? At least we (indirectly) change the object state of an association when calling a `const`-classified method**.
- **In case this is undefined behaviour: will this be defined again if I declare the `_money` attribute of the `DonationsAccount` to be `mutable`? Could you expand on what `mutable` exactly does and why it helps (if it does)?**
- **Is there a better way to achieve the above behaviour?**

---

For further clarification, some remarks:

- I am not actually dealing with accounts etc, this is just a made up example that semantically (more or less) fits. So this is not about security etc, but `const`-correctness of my program
- To be more concrete, the Association in above example corresponds to some graph managing (and owning) nodes and edges. Nodes and edges don't exist outside of a graph, since this would be semantically meaningless. I want to grant users access to the nodes of this graph (stored in a vector), but of course not allow the user to just swap out this vector etc, so I return a const reference. It would however still make sense that the user can call stuff like "add an edge" on certain nodes, since I can control these semantically correct operations on nodes and ensure things like range-checking etc, which is handled by the graph itself.
- So essentially, I would like to return a reference that is not const (since we want to allow for adding edges etc), but has a state that forbids stuff like assignment / deletion / moving the object away, but allows certain methods like "add an edge", "remove node" (this will have side effects on the graph that have to be controlled, thus this is different from just deleting the node)

Comment: `const` is not transitive, which is why the code works.  The code is going through contortions to avoid a `const_cast`.  The code would break if the object was actually `const`, but it isn't, so it's okay.

Comment: The `DonationsAccount ` object may be `const`, but the contained `_association` is not, so any member of `DonationsAccount` can make changes to any `_association` member.

Comment: `DonationsAccount::donate` does not override base donate, it instead defines a new prototype, unlike `Association::donate` which may modify account.